# apply template to current page not children

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I know about ext templates and the option where you can select the Template on Next Level:

However I just want to add something to one page only (not the children) and I think it would be a bit of a waste to have to make an ext template then another one for the children so I am trying to use some conditions. see [this link for details](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/4/).

If I do the below

```
[PIDinRootline = 10]
...
[end]
```

it works but also includes children.

I have tried the below but it doesn't seem to work?

```
[PIDinRootline = 10 && treeLevel = 1]
...
[end]
```

Any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Comment: Do you really use `TYPO3` ver 4.1? o.O Respect

Comment: @biesior no I am on the LTS 4.5 when I googled PIDinRootline that doc came up, I will be sure to look more closely at that next time thanks!

Comment: OK, although there are no bigger changes in TSref for `conditions` it's better to use version of document 'nearest' used version of TYPO3, you'll avoid annoying 'traps'. http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use condition:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 10]
    ...
[end]
```

for exact targeting page's uids

additionally you can use `operators` such as `||` (OR) or `&&` (AND) for more sophisticated combinations, ie:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 10] || [globalVar = TSFE:id = 978]
```

It will work on pages with `uid`: 10 `OR` 978